# Lenovo w540 with 16.04 fails to detect docking station screen after waking up from sleep

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, lenovo, docking

I've been having this problem for a while and it's really annoying... Every evening when I undock my lenovo it goes to sleep. The next morning when I re-dock it it wakes up but does not detect the screen I have connected to the docking station.

A restart solves this but of course I prefer not restarting my machine every morning.

Any more info I can provide please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Any news on the topic?

Comment: I never managed to get it working

Comment: I think my issue is a little bit different: when I put it to sleep while docked, and wake it (while undocked) it does not detect the laptop monitor and I am forced to hard reboot...Is it the same issue you are experiencing? Otherwise, I will open a new question.

Comment: Seems different but related. For me it was always when I docked the machine after it was already sleeping.